# Replace or trim string based on where the time is

Tags: regex, powershell

In Powershell, I have been working with regex and trying to trim strings based on where the time is in it. Currently, a person inputs the string manually so it can come in multiple ways. The format of the data is this

```
$appointment = "Certified Substitute Orientation (Session 1) - 9:00 AM - 11:00 AM"
$appointment = "TBI 101 1:00 pm - 3:00 pm"
```

The titles change and the times could be resprented differently every time. It could be: 9am, 9 am, 9:00, etc. and I want to try and find a way to key off of the time, because it won't always be in the same place.

I am a novice at this stuff. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you.

I know this is a lot to ask, but I have tried messing with code that looks like this and can't seem to get it to work:

```
If ($appointment -like "*Session 1*") {
  $appointment1 = $appointment
  $appointment = $appointment -creplace '[^1-9]*'
  $appointment=$appointment.substring(0,$appointment.subject.length-1)
  $appointment1 = $appointment1 -replace '-' -replace "[(]","" -replace "[)]","" -replace "event","" -replace "'" -replace '[,]',' ' -replace "   "," " -replace "  "," " -replace '[\d+]:.*'
  }
```

My goal is to split the string right before the time so that I have:

```
$appointment1 = "Certified Substitute Orientation (Session 1)"
$appointment2 = "9:00 AM - 11:00 AM"
```

Comment: Users *will* come up with more variations then you can possibly hope to get right. You really should fix this at the input side.

Comment: `$str -split '(?=\d{1,2}:\d{1,2} [AP]M)'`

Comment: To hard to resist though: `[regex]::Matches($appointment, '(\d+:\d+.(?:[ap]m)?)', [System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::IgnoreCase) | % {$_.Value}`

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers FWIW, `-match` is case-insensitive by default and populates the `$Matches` automatic variable.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 - I tried that but couldn't get it right :(. Feel free to improve on my comment (and teach me).

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers `$appointment -match '(\d+:\d+.(?:[ap]m)?)'; $Matches`

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 - does that work for you? It didn't work for me. I get two matches but both contain the first match.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers Thought that was your goal with the non-capture group (`?:`)

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 - the goal was to get both times?! This `"TBI 101 1:00 pm - 3:00 pm" -match '(\d+:\d+.(?:[ap]m)?)'; $Matches` returns `1:00 pm` two times instead of `1:00 pm` and `3:00 pm`

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers Oh, huh.  That's weird calling the regex class directly has different results from the match operator.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 - I assumed it was my lack of knowledge but if you are baffled by it too, perhaps it has the marking of good new question ;)

Comment: This would work but I can't get the `$Matches` to behave as expected `"TBI 101 1:00 pm - 3:00 pm" -split "(\d+:\d+.(?:[ap]m)?)" -match "(\d+:\d+.(?:[ap]m)?)"`

Comment: [This](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/66107c99-67c4-40bc-b49a-f0134c4235b3/powershell-matches-collection) explains it: *The -match operator wll return the first match found.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a more complex RegEx you can even separate the session:

```
## Q:\Test\2019\08\22\SO_57614115.ps1
$appointments = @"
Certified Substitute Orientation (Session 1) - 9:00 AM - 11:00 AM
TBI 101 1:00 pm - 3:00 pm
"@ -split '\r?\n'

$RE = '^(?<title>.*?)[-_ ]*(?<session>\([^\)]*\))?[-_ ]*(?<from>1?\d:[0-5]\d\s*[ap]m)[-_ ]+(?<to>1?\d:[0-5]\d\s*[ap]m)$'

Foreach($appointment in $appointments){
    if ($appointment -match $RE){
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Title   = $Matches.title
            Session = $Matches.session
            From    = $Matches.from.ToUpper()
            To      = $Matches.to.ToUpper()
        }
    } else {
        "doesn't match RE: $appointment"
    }
}
```

the script yields:

```
> Q:\Test\2019\08\22\SO_57614115.ps1
Title                            Session     From    To
-----                            -------     ----    --
Certified Substitute Orientation (Session 1) 9:00 AM 11:00 AM
TBI 101                                      1:00 PM 3:00 PM
```